luaotfload-tool: This version of luaotfload may have been tampered with. Is this a software bug, packaging bug or user malfunction?
Bug reports
See also Max Chernoff's comment. Thanks to Max for directions to the first and prompting the second and third.

https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/277
https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/281
https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/282

Version
Vanilla (i.e. upstream) TeX Live 2024 not-quite-current.
$ luaotfload-tool --version

luaotfload-tool:
Luaotfload font management and diagnostic utility.
License: GNU GPL v2.0.
Report problems to <https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues>

luaotfload-tool version: "3.28"
Revision: nil
Lua interpreter: stock; version "Lua 5.3"
Luatex version: 1.18
Platform: type=unix name=linux
+  machine: x86_64
+ nodename: MyComputer
+  release: 6.8.2-arch2-1
+  sysname: Linux
+  version: #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 28 Mar 2024 17:06:35 +0000
Index: version=6 created="2024-03-26 19:18:36" modified="2024-04-05 01:10:24"

and
$ tlmgr info luaotfload
package:     luaotfload
category:    Package
shortdesc:   OpenType 'loader' for Plain TeX and LaTeX
longdesc:    The package adopts the TrueType/OpenType Font loader code provided in ConTeXt, and adapts it to use in Plain TeX and LaTeX. It works under LuaLaTeX only.
installed:   Yes
revision:    70232
sizes:       src: 25k, doc: 1105k, run: 7665k, bin: 5k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 3.28
cat-license: gpl2
cat-topics:  font-use luatex
cat-contact-support: https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues
cat-contact-repository: https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload
collection:  collection-luatex

Problems
I do not use LuaTeX much but, as far as I can tell, the engine has no trouble finding and using fonts on my system.
--find
However, if I try to use luaotfload-tool at the command line, it is a different story. It has no problem generating a list of fonts or reporting its version or relaying its help message, but attempting to search the database fails.
$ luaotfload-tool --find "Noto Sans"
...4/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-arabic.lua:19: attempt to index a nil value (global 'node')

--diagnose=files
Attempting to diagnose this, I tried the first of the 'CHECK' options listed in the help message.
$ luaotfload-tool --diagnose=files
luaotfload | diagnose : ================ verify files =================
luaotfload | diagnose : Luaotfload revision 73dac18445938c6c54118045944817c4e8c59a1c.
luaotfload | diagnose : Committed by Marcel Fabian Krüger <tex@2krueger.de>.
luaotfload | diagnose : Timestamp 2024-02-28 06:18:10 +0100.
luaotfload | diagnose : Testing 88 files for integrity.
<successful lines omitted>
luaotfload | diagnose : FAILED: file mktests missing.
luaotfload | diagnose : FAILED: file mkstatus missing.
luaotfload | diagnose : FAILED: file mkcharacters missing.
luaotfload | diagnose : FAILED: file mkglyphlist missing.
luaotfload | diagnose : FAILED: file mkimport missing.
<successful lines omitted>
luaotfload | diagnose : ===============================================
WARNING
===============================================

The diagnostic detected 5 errors.

This version of luaotfload may have been
tampered with. Modified versions of the
luaotfload source are unsupported. Read the log
carefully and get a clean version from CTAN or
github:

× http://www.ctan.org/pkg/luaotfload
× https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/releases

If you are uncertain as to how to proceed, then
ask on the lualatex mailing list:

http://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/lualatex-dev

===============================================

The message seems unduly alarmist, to be honest. While it is possible that somebody has tampered with my copy of luaotfload-tool, it doesn't seem terribly likely. (If it is an attempt to do something nefarious, it seems a singularly inept one.)
What of the remaining 'checks'?

environment, index and repository all tell me I may sleep well.
repository nonetheless reports no access to the repository, but that is expected as I'm using TeX Live's package.

--diagnose=permissions
But permissions again reports trouble:
luaotfload | diagnose : =============== file permissions ==============
luaotfload | diagnose : Checking permissions of /home/username/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/.
luaotfload | diagnose : Owner: 1000, group 1000, permissions rwxr-xr-x.
luaotfload | diagnose : Readable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Writable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Checking permissions of /home/username/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | diagnose : Owner: 1000, group 1000, permissions rwxr-xr-x.
luaotfload | diagnose : Readable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Writable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Checking permissions of /home/username/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.lua.gz.
luaotfload | diagnose : Owner: 1000, group 1000, permissions rw-r--r--.
luaotfload | diagnose : Readable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Writable: ok.
luaotfload | diagnose : Checking permissions of /home/username/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.

attr    /home/username/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc   nil

This fails because the file doesn't exist. luaotfload-names.luc is present, but only in compressed format as luaotfload-names.luc.gz. This is apparently fine when using LuaTeX but not fine with luaotfload-tool.
Summary
So I apparently have not one but two problems:

luaotfload-tool expects to find 5 non-existent scripts which are not present in (my copy of) the TeX Live package.
luaotfload-tool expects to find a database of names in uncompressed format, but (by default, at least) the database is only created in compressed format.

Are these software errors, packaging errors, intended modifications or just user idiocy?
Note: I'm not providing an MWE precisely because it would be an MWE rather than an MNWE --- I've not seen any problems compiling documents.

I tried running luaotfload-tool --find "Noto Sans" and luaotfload-tool --diagnose=files directly on the tug.org server, and I get the exact same error messages. So this seems to be a bug; probably best to report it in the luaotfload bug tracker. It looks like the --find issue has already been reported and fixed upstream; the --diagnose issue was supposedly fixed in 2020, but it looks like it's back again.

@MaxChernoff Thanks. I should have time to do that later. It's good to know it isn't just me, however unlikely that seemed. I do think the error message is a bit over the top. In my experience bugs are common; tampering relatively rare. (Recent events notwithstanding.)
